# For Each Loop to return search string

Tags: java, foreach, arraylist

I'm having trouble with my JAVA command line menu. Here's what I've got.. what I want to do is in the comments.

```
 private void listStudents(){
    out.println("\n\tStudent Listing");
    //Call datastore method that returns all student names as an array of strings
    String[] list = data.getStudents();
    //Display all names (use foreach statement)
    for (String name : list) {

    }
}
```

here's the data store method I'm also stuck with...

```
 String[] getStudents() {
    return (String[]) students.toArray();
}

// Method to return students who match search term
String[] findStudents(String searchTerms) {
// Use foreach loop to visit each item in students ArrayList,
// and if the name matches the search term, add it to a new ArraList.
// Then return the new ArrayList as a string array (see getStudents)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you're stuck with that method, what have you actually tried that isn't working? We're glad to help, but this is pretty much a "show your work" type of site - when you say something isn't working, you should include what isn't working. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks. Umm well I haven't really tried anything, I'm completely blanked of what to do. Thanks for the introduction :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but based on what I understood from your comments, try using the following:

```
private void listStudents()
{
    System.out.println("\n\tStudent Listing");

    String[] list = data.getStudents();

    // List each student.
    for (String name : list)
        System.out.println(name);
}

private String[] findStudents(String searchTerms)
{
    List<String> studentsFound = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String student : students)
    {
        // Determine if matching student found.
        if (student.equals(searchTerms))
            studentsFound.add(student);
    }

    return studentsFound.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not defined what the `searchterms` might.  Is it a regular expression?  Is it a wildcard?

```
public String[] findStudents(String searchTerms) {
    List<String> findList = new ArrayList<String>(25);
    for (String student : students) {

        // Now you'll need to define how the match works,
        // Are you using a regexp or some kind of other matching
        // algorithm..
        boolean match = ...;
        if (match) {

            findList.add(student);

        }

    }

    return findList.toArray(new String[findList.size()]);
}
```